# Why dandvat pranam has more importance?

Tags: temple

In Hindu temples we can see that many people does Dandvat Pranam.

[image]

Why it is consider as more important than normal namaskara mudra ?

Comment: literally means lying before diety as a stick in order to make full sharanagati(devoting everything) even the body's 8 limbs by touching the ground make it true. see this http://www.baps.org/cultureandheritage/Traditions/HinduPractices/DandavatPranam.aspx for more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So Krisna worship, mad-yaji, worshiping Krisna... Krisna says, "Worship
>   Me."  What is that? Mam namaskuru.
>
> If you simply come in this temple and offer little obeisances,
>   dandavat...  Danda, danda means "rod";  vat means "like."
>
> Just like one stick falls straight on the ground, similarly, if we
>   fall straight before the Deity, that is called dandavat, "like the
>   stick."
>
> Dandavat-pranama. Prakrsta-rupena namrata.  Namrata is required. 
>   Jnane prayasam udapasya namanta eva.  Namanta. Be submissive.  So this
>   dandavat is the symbolic presentation of submission.
>
> And Krisna wants that sarva-dharman parityajya mam ekam saranam vraja
>   [Bg. 18.66], submission. The bhakti process is simply submission. So
>   mad-yajino 'pi yanti mam [Bg. 9.25].

Those who have not studied Vedic literatures. The temples are installed for this(Dandavat-pranama) purpose. If somebody comes, simply offers his obeisances before the Deity or before the spiritual master simply by doing that(Dandavat-pranama), he will become perfect.

Source: [Prabhupadavani](http://www.prabhupadavani.org/main/Bhagavatam/397.html)